# How to set the Message empty in java

Tags: java

I need to clear the message, if `Value`'s length is not equal to zero...

So, I am trying this way as given below...

```
if (Value.length() == 0)
{
    setMessage("Template name not specified");
    return false;
}

else
{
    setMessage("");
}
```

Is this the correct and efficient way or any other way is possible?

Otherwise, if I assign `null` value to string and use it in `setMessage()`, will it work?

Comment: Where did you cut out this code snippet?

Comment: please post full code. what setMessage does?

Comment: Have you actually tried any of the solutions you are mentioning in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a few things here and there:-

```
if (Value.trim().length() == 0) { // So that even if "Value" contains spaces, it can be taken as 0
    setMessage("Template name not specified");
    return false;
}

else {
    setMessage(null); // It'll be better to use "null" instead of a blank string. or may be some custom String of your own choice.
    return true/false; // You missed this statement as your return is conditional here!
}
```

Comment: It can be "dangerous" to use `null` when the code is used somewhere else and the assumption is made that the string is effective.

Furthermore I doubt "" would cause that much overhead. Strings are immutable and therefore they can be reused for instance like the Flyweight pattern. I think Java will store the empty string somewhere in the bytecode (in memory) and reuse it.

Comment: String class contains `isEmpty()` method so it will be better to use it instead of `value.lenght()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.isEmpty("")        = true
String.isEmpty(null)      = true
String.isEmpty(" ")       = false
String.isEmpty("fix")     = false
String.isEmpty("  fix  ") = false
```

`""` means the string is empty and it's a good way. `null` can also refer to emptiness.

You can check whether a string is empty or not using `.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be

```
   setMessage(""); // without space between quotes;
```

Its the Fastest and efficient way

Answer (score 0):

A  way I follow usually,

```
private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

setMessage(EMPTY_STRING );
```

Since it's a message you might showing it some where,If you set it to `null`,it displays as `"null"`  to end user.

on there other hand you can check with `isEmpty`  method.

Answer (score 0):

> is this the correct and efficient way(setMessage(""))

Yes, it is correct and efficient.

> or any other exact way is possible....

Yes, other ways are possible.  However, this is (IMO) the best way.

> otherwise i need to assaign null value to string and using it in setMessage() will be fine?

Using a `null` is possible instead of `""`, but it has the problem that what ever is using the message value needs to be able to cope with a `null`.  An empty String (`""`) is easier to deal with.  Indeed, in most cases you don't need to deal with `""` any different to a non-empty message.